# 1-2 seconds Page was blank in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

We have recently update Codeigniter 3.1.2 and got one problem.

1-2 seconds Page was blank when redirect one page to another page / Form submission in CodeIgniter 3.

Comment: are you using  redirect('controllerNme', 'refresh') for redirection ?

Comment: No . I am just using form action

Comment: No. I am using below cases , 

a) redirect('/controller/function');
b) <form action="/controller/function">
c) $this->filename->function-name

                             The 3 cases i have faced the issues. Please help me..

Comment: if you are redirecting on a specific reason then it will be blank. don't use a direct form action. use button on click function in js(ajaxcall), will work faster.

Comment: use `redirect('/controller/function', 'location', 301);` or `redirect('/controller/function', 'location', 302);`

Comment: Don't let your `base_ur`empty in confg file `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name/'` ;


use `<form action = base_url('controllerName')   method="post" >`  for form submission